# Why does inserting empty string into date column produce 1900-01-01

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

Why does an empty string, `''`, get rendered as `'1900-01-01'` but a `NULL` value is left `NULL`?

```sql
create table "dbo"."day" (day date)
insert into "dbo"."day" (day) values (NULL), ('')
select day from "dbo"."day"
```

```
day
NULL
1900-01-01
```

This is a more simplified example which also returns `1900-01-01`:

```sql
SELECT CAST('' as date)
```

Comment: I guess for '' implicit type conversion takes place, so '' is replaced by default date, 1900-01-01

Comment: Where did the blanks come from? Are you trying to import a CSV file with optional date fields perhaps? In that case you should configure your import code to replace empty fields with nulls. *Some* import methods allow you to configure this per field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A NULL date is NULL (unknown value). An empty string, on the other hand, evaluates to 0, which in SQL Server is implicitly an integer representing the number of days since 1900-01-01. You can reference this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/89945).
So when we try to insert `''` to a date type column, it is equals to  insert `1900-01-01`.